# How to play video in react image gallery when clicked for e-commerce project? Need to play video in the carousel itself

Tags: reactjs

I have an image slider built using react image gallery and populated with images from backend for an e-commerce project. When there is a product with video, show video image and when clicked on the image play video inside the carousel.

I had tried to implement react image gallery demo code given but unable to get a successful result.

```
<div className="leftSlider">
                    <ImageGallery ref={el => this.imagegallery = el}
                        thumbnailPosition={window.matchMedia('(min-width: 600px)').matches ? 'left' : 'bottom'}
                        showFullscreenButton={false}
                        showPlayButton={false}
                        showNav={false}
                        renderItem={this.imageHover}
                        showThumbnails={this.showThumbnails(Object.keys(this.state.images) ? this.state.images[selectedVariant] : [])}
                        items={Object.keys(this.state.images) ? this.state.images[selectedVariant] : []}
                        onSlide={(slide) => this.onslide(slide)}/></div>
```

Expected result is exactly the same like shown in the demo of react-image-gallery

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery

Comment: Please do help me urgently. I have been trying for past two days with no success

Answer (score 0):

There is an example created by package author where he uses custom itemRender for video media.
He is rendering video on description click, but you can of course change it to immediately render video in the slider.

Whole application can be seen:
https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/blob/master/example/app.js

```
// items
{
    thumbnail: `${PREFIX_URL}4v.jpg`,
    original: `${PREFIX_URL}4v.jpg`,
    embedUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/4pSzhZ76GdM?autoplay=1&showinfo=0',
    description: 'Render custom slides within the gallery',
    renderItem: this._renderVideo.bind(this)
},

_renderVideo(item) {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.showVideo[item.embedUrl] ?
            <div className='video-wrapper'>
                <a
                  className='close-video'
                  onClick={this._toggleShowVideo.bind(this, item.embedUrl)}
                >
                </a>
                <iframe
                  width='560'
                  height='315'
                  src={item.embedUrl}
                  frameBorder='0'
                  allowFullScreen
                >
                </iframe>
            </div>
          :
            <a onClick={this._toggleShowVideo.bind(this, item.embedUrl)}>
              <div className='play-button'></div>
              <img className='image-gallery-image' src={item.original} />
              {
                item.description &&
                  <span
                    className='image-gallery-description'
                    style={{right: '0', left: 'initial'}}
                  >
                    {item.description}
                  </span>
              }
            </a>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with it and I achieved it with a simple video tag render.

I created a separate file for gallery renders (`galleryRenders.tsx`) just in case I will need some more in future. So far it contains only this:

```
export const renderVideoUrl = (video) => {
  return (
    <video controls muted>
      <source src={video.original} />
    </video>
  )
}
```

my array of media contains also `type` property which can be anything but if it has value `video` I am able to attach `renderItem property` to it

so looping through media items before assigning it as property to `<ImageGallery items={media} />`

Loop:

```
import { renderVideoUrl } from "../../functions/galleryRenders";

media.forEach((item, i) => {
  if(item.type === 'video'){
    media[i].renderItem = renderVideoUrl.bind(media[i])
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, I just used a renderVideo function with iframe,
check this out. insert a renderItem in your object for video

```
 const images = [
        {
          original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/',
          thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/',
        },
        {
          original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/',
          thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/',
        },
        {
          original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/',
          thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/',
        },
        {
          embedUrl:
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/4pSzhZ76GdM?autoplay=1&showinfo=0',
          original:
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/master/static/4v.jpg',
          thumbnail:
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/master/static/4v.jpg',
          renderItem: renderVideo.bind(this),
        },
      ];
    

 const renderVideo = (item) => {
    return (
      <div className="video-wrapper">
        <iframe
          width="100%"
          height="480px"
          src={item.embedUrl}
          frameBorder="0"
          allowFullScreen
          title="ex"
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

then in my ImageGallery component from react-image-gallery used it
like this.

```
 <ImageGallery
                  items={images}
                  showIndex
                  onSlide={handleSlideChange}
                  showVideo={showVideo}
                  showPlayButton
                />
```